# Model of the nucleus as fermi gas

Tags: nuclear-physics, fermions, metals

I am taking an *introductory* course in modern physics, and am reviewing some of the exams from previous years. In our course, we studies the Fermi gas model for electrons in a metal. In one of the exams, they are asking to use this Fermi gas model to model the nucleus.

How do I extend this concept to calculate the Fermi energy (which I only know for electrons) for a system of protons and neutrons, and determine what will happens to such a system with a given number of initial nucleons?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: @JohnRennie I have veen using SE for over a year now, and I think I have made it pretty clear that this is not a homework question, it's a conceptual question. Maybe if you clarify what makes you typify this as a homework question, I could alter my formulation.

Comment: *"Calculate the Fermi energy"* is not a conceptual question.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Let me rephrase the question, to clear up my intentions.

Comment: One question: are protons and neutrons identical to one another? From the answer to that question forward there is nothing new.

Comment: @dmckee Yes, except for some analogous feat to the electron's spin value, which makes the neutron slightly more massive (energetic), and hence the proton the more stable state. What exactly is this 'spin' value?

Comment: It's called "isospin". But you don't need it. Just treat them as different.

Comment: @dmckee thanks! Can the analogy be taken as far as to say that the electric repulsion is equivalent to thermal agitation, so that you get more neutrons/protons as the electric repulsion get's stronger?

Comment: @dmckee but the Pauli principle is only valid between identical particles... So I don't see how it should work BETWEEN protons and neutrons...

Comment: You're following the right lines of reasoning; asking the right questions. Now might be the time to dive into trying to compute an answer, but I'll give you one more teaser: do you need to have a thermal agitation or should the system be in a low energy state? Why?